# How to make rollback to state mentioned in one connection if another connection changed some table row?

Tags: java, database, postgresql, jdbc, transactions

I'm trying to use rollback on savepoint in my connection, but changes done in another connection are seen in mine even if I rollback to my savepoint.

Comment: the changes in the other transaction are commited?

Comment: Yes, they are done in another process

Answer (score 0):

That is how "read committed" works, which is the [default isolation level](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.2/xact-read-committed.html) for postgres.  Using savepoints doesn't automatically move you out of "read committed".  You have to set your isolation level to "repeatable read", if that is what you want.

Comment: Right, it is the "default default".  You can change the default to something else by setting `default_transaction_isolation`.